# C# Check if Object is a casted child of parent object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I couldn't really explain that better but I will give you an example of my case:

I have a class type called "Item"
Item has a subclass that inherits it that's called "Weapon"
and Weapon has a subclass that's called "RangedWeapon"

Now my player can swap and use items at will, but since they are all items and I am not looking for errors, all items the player equips are displayed as Item class. And so, if I equip a ranged weapon, for example, a gun, in my player script it will still be considered an Item and I will only be able to access properties Item has and not the RangedWeapon's additional properties. My question is if I have an Item object how can I check whether it was originally a Weapon or a RangedWeapon?

If something is not clear please ask me for it and I'll explain more further.

I appreciate all your comments :)

**EDIT**

Code Example:

Let's just say I have a RangedWeapon object called gun.

```
RangedWeapon gun = new RangedWeapon(*parameters here*);
```

In my player script I have an Item value that stores the currently held item:

```
//Some stuff above

private Item heldItem;

//etc
```

Whenever I equip an item the item is being stored in the "heldItem" variable.
So if I were to equip gun this would happen:

```
heldItem = gun;
```

Now this code is valid because gun is a RangedWeapon and RangedWeapon inherits from Item, but what if I don't know what item I equip and whether it was originally an Item, Weapon or RangedWeapon? How can I retrieve its original type via the heldItem?

For example:
If I could do something like(This is totally a pseudo code for the sake of the example)

```
if (typeof(heldItem) was RangedWeapon) {//stuff}
else if (typeof(heldItem) was Weapon) {//stuff}
```

Hope I made myself clearer :)

Comment: isn´t a ranged weapon also a weapon? The point of inheritance is that you have common behaviour which yiu encapsulate in base-classes.

Comment: Yes, it is, weapon has properties Item doesn't have and Ranged weapon has properties weapon doesn't have

Comment: Item has a Mesh, Name Right and left click sounds, price and etc, weapon adds damage and attack rate, and ranged weapon adds ammo, range and reload sound

Comment: Could you please provide some code that shows your issue? From what you´ve posted it´s hard to guess what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Can´t you just cast your instance to a more specific type? e.g. `Weapon o = myItem as Weapon`.

Comment: `if (item is RangedWeapon) { RangedWeapon rw = (RangedWeapon) item; // access RangedWeapon properties of rw here }`

Comment: @Rufus L wait the "is" keyword is gonna work here? I mean what if I were to ask if it was a Weapon and it was a RangedWeapon, it would still return true because a RangedWeapon is a Weapon... I guess in that case you can put them in the right order.. but does it have a chance to throw an error or mistake Items that weren't RangedWeapons into RangedWeapons?

Comment: Take a minute and try it out, or read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is). But yes, it will return `true` if the item is of the specified type (both `Weapon` and `RangedWeapon` would return true). But this is not a great way to go - it's not a maintainable design at all. You'll end up with too many `if` statements all over the place. Ideally you only treat them as `Item` objects when that's all you need.

Comment: Thank you, I am giving it a try right now. And I think I can avoid this confusion by first checking if it is a RangedWeapon and if it is not a RangedWeapon but is a Weapon I can avoid confusion. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Or check for a weapon first, and if that's true, then check for more specific types of weapons. But again, this is not a great design.

Comment: @RufusL What design would you recommend then? If I may ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**:

The question was answered by @RufusL I am just posting it as an answer and not as a comment for it to be more easily seen.

The solution is to simply use the `is` operator.

I quote:

> ```
>  if (item is RangedWeapon) { RangedWeapon rw = (RangedWeapon) item; //
>  access RangedWeapon properties of rw here }
> ```

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but please feel free to post this as your own answer - i.e. post the actual code that's working for you and describe how it solved your problem. No need to mention my comment, but thank you.

Comment: Nah it was your solution in the first place, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this would be to use an `interface` instead of a `class` in your list of items. Interfaces are nice because they define a contract - a set of public methods and properties that are guaranteed to exist, but the classes themselves define the implementation.

The problem with a `List<Item>` is that all the members of the list are down-cast (not sure if that's a correct term) to `Item`, and only that base class implementation of any common method will be called.

With an interface, each object in the list retains the implementation of it's specific type, so we can get different results from different types of objects when calling the same method.

Here's an example, it is probably not the best but I think it illustrates the point:

```
// This interface defines the public members that we want to access from any Item
public interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void Click();
}

// This class may be a base class for other items, but it's *NOT* a base class for
// Weapon. Instead, Weapon will implement a common interface with other items
public class Item : IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Item";

    public void Click()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} was selected!");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

// Here we have Weapon as a base class that implements the IItem interface,
// (and contains the default implementation for sub classes)
public class Weapon : IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Weapon";

    public void Click()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = FireColor;
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} was fired!");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    // FireColor is protected, meaning it's only available to
    // this class and classes that derive from this class
    protected ConsoleColor FireColor { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Red;
}

// Now we have a class that derives from the Weapon 
// base class, and changes the Name property
public class Pistol : Weapon
{
    public Pistol()
    {
        Name = "Pistol";
    }
}

// And an additional class that derives from 
// Weapon, which changes both Name and FireColor
public class RangedWeapon : Weapon
{
    public RangedWeapon()
    {
        FireColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Name = "Ranged Weapon";
    }
}
```

Now, when we want to have a collection of items, we create a collection of objects that implement the `IItem` interface, rather than a specific, concrete class. This way we get all the common methods, but the behavior from the actual class types:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Add three unique objects that implement 'IItem' to a list
    var items = new List<IItem>
    {
        new Item(),
        new Pistol(),
        new RangedWeapon()
    };

    // Call the 'Click' method for each 'IItem' object
    items.ForEach(item => item.Click());

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

Note that in the output we have a different color for each item, and the text is different between `Item` and `Weapon` (i.e. `"selected"` vs `"fired"`), and each item displays it's unique `Name`. Also, the pistol uses the base-class implementation for `FireColor` (red) while the `RangedWeapon` implemented it's own color.

[image]